# How to track motherboard number by vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Can you help me to track the motherboard number in vb.net

Answer (score 1):

**Retrieving Motherboard Serial Number using WMI** 
http://www.codegain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=345

It's in C#, but it should be fairly simple to convert it to VB.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open-ended question and an impossible one to answer.  You need a lot of low-level information that simply is not readily available.  Further, "motherboard number" can mean a variety of different things.

So to answer your "Can you..." question, the answer would be "no" given the information given.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get this information via WMI (a type of Windows-specific SNMP). It provides many information about the system, e.g. the BIOS serial no, maybe you should give it a try. There's WMI-Support in the .NET-Framework.